# Retrieve list items in subsite using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have a site called `Testing`. I want to retrieve list items from a list in one of the subsites using REST API. How can this be done?

Comment: Please refer this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask before drafting your question. Provide detailed description and efforts about your problem so one can understand it properly.

Comment: Hi Krishna, Do you want to retrieve the list items from single list or multiple list. Please provide more information

Comment: @shantha kumar Thambidurai single list.

Answer (score 5):

Approach is same for sub-site or main site. The only thing matter is **URL**

```
{sub or main site url}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/Items
```

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

You will get the full document in my above article.